# Как перезаписать(обновить) БД MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть база на удаленном сервере. На локальном сервере сделаны изменения в БД. Как правильно накатить изменения на удаленной базе?

Comment: Составить запросы изменения структуры и данных. Выполнить их на удалённом сервере.

Comment: тогда не проще ли удалить старую и экспортировать обновленную?

Comment: @Proshka Далеко не всегда. Зависит, к примеру, от размера базы и скорости соединения.

Comment: база весит 3 метра - делов-то

Comment: Данные тоже нужно? или достаточно обновить схему, согласно локальной?

Comment: @Mr. Brightside именно данные и нужно обновить

Comment: @Proshka тогда я присоединяюсь к совету Akina

Comment: @Proshka А это уже только Вы можете решить, что проще - обновлять БД или грохнуть и поднять из актуального бэкапа...